# How to use tooltip option in odoo to show some error message?

Tags: tooltip, odoo-8

Currently i am developing a module in Odoo. I need to validate some constraints. If the constraints returns a false value, i need to show an  error message using tooltip. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using api.constrains:

```
@api.one
@api.constrains('field')
def _function_of_constrain(self):
if x:
    raise ValidationError("The field is incorrect")
```

Every time you write 'field' it will run that function and check the constrain.